# Shiny app is not available when singularity container is run as instance

Tags: r, docker, shiny, containers, singularity-container

I built singularity container from docker image `kfoltynski/shinyproxy-demo:singularity`. When I run

```
singularity run shiny.simg 3839
```

shiny app is available on `localhost:3839`, but after running singularity container as instance

```
singularity instance start shiny.simg shiny 3839
```

it is not. Why?

Steps to reproduce:

**[Dockerfile](https://github.com/Tazovsky/shinyproxy-demo/blob/singularity-test/Dockerfile):**

```
FROM openanalytics/r-base

MAINTAINER Tobias Verbeke "Tazovsky"

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    sudo \
    pandoc \
    pandoc-citeproc \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libcairo2-dev \
    libxt-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libssh2-1-dev \
    libssl1.0.0

# packages needed for basic shiny functionality
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('shiny', 'rmarkdown'), repos='https://cloud.r-project.org')"

# install shinyproxy package with demo shiny application
COPY shinyproxy /shinyproxy
RUN R CMD INSTALL /shinyproxy
RUN rm /shinyproxy

# set host and port
COPY Rprofile.site /usr/lib/R/etc/

EXPOSE 3838

ENV PORT=3839

CMD ["R", "-e", "shinyproxy::run_01_hello(as.numeric(Sys.getenv(\"PORT\")))"]
```

Singularity def/recipe file `Singularity.recipe`:

```
Bootstrap: docker

From: kfoltynski/shinyproxy-demo:singularity

%environment

    export PORT=3839

%runscript

    echo "Running Shiny app on port $*"

    exec R -e "shinyproxy::run_01_hello($@)"
```

**Build singularity image `shiny.simg`:**

```
 sudo singularity build shiny.simg Singularity.recipe
```

**Run container:**

```
singularity run shiny.simg 3839 # app is available on port 3839
```

**Run container as instance:**

```
singularity instance start shiny.simg shiny 3839 # app is not available on port 3839
```

Why app is not available when running singularity container as instance?

Answer (score 0):

`singularity instance start shiny.simg shiny 3839` is creating and starting a new instance named `3839`, and not passing that as a param to the `%runscript`. To get the response you want you need to run:

```sh
singularity instance start shiny.simg shiny_instance
singularity run instance://shiny_instance 3839
```

The `%runscript` block is not called when the instance is started. If you want a process to run when the instance is started you need to use the `%startscript` directive, [shown in the docs here](https://www.sylabs.io/guides/3.2/user-guide/running_services.html#nginx-hello-world-in-singularity).

e.g.,

```
Bootstrap: docker

From: kfoltynski/shinyproxy-demo:singularity

%environment
    export PORT=3839

%runscript
    echo "Running Shiny app on port $*"
    exec R -e "shinyproxy::run_01_hello($@)"

%startscript
    exec R -e "shinyproxy::run_01_hello($@)"
```